# Django equivalent for has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, authentication

I recently started learning Rails, and came across the has_secure_password. This is cool, since it takes care of hashing the password, creating the digest and ensuring that the password and confirm_password are similar.

My question is does Django have something similar that does this. The Django forms, as far as I know, only take in the password and if you want to add the password confirmation you need to manually check if the 2 password's are similar.

Appreciate your feedback. 
Thanks

Comment: Any one with any more information on this ?